# Tweet reply tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to make a script in Python to reply to certain keywords on Twitter with Tweepy. I found this code on Google and tried it out. For some reason the Python screen automaticly closes without doing anything.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tweepy
#from our keys module (keys.py), import the keys dictionary
from keys import keys

CONSUMER_KEY = keys['consumer_key']
CONSUMER_SECRET = keys['consumer_secret']
ACCESS_TOKEN = keys['access_token']
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = keys['access_token_secret']

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

twt = api.search(q="Hello World!")     

#list of specific strings we want to check for in Tweets
t = ['Hello world!',
    'Hello World!',
    'Hello World!!!',
    'Hello world!!!',
    'Hello, world!',
    'Hello, World!']

for s in twt:
    for i in t:
        if i == s.text:
            sn = s.user.screen_name
            m = "@%s Hello!" % (sn)
            s = api.update_status(m, s.id)
```

am I doing something wrong? I tried to open it in the module but I get this:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
```

Im not a coder or progammer but I would like to know how to get this working.
Thanks,

Comment: have you created the keys.py file for your own app ? Have you filled all the 4 tokens correctly?

Comment: `s.text` and `s.user.screen_name` won't work if you haven't converted the received data in a particular format , actually the `twt` object here is a json file which is more like a python dictionary , So to access the required elements you should try using `s['text']` and `s['user']['screen_name']`